# How do I do `group by` partial match

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a table in SQL-server with projectcodes and sub-project-codes in the same fields.

The stucture is something like this

```
+----+------+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| id | date | projectcode | debit | credit | budget |
+----+------+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| 1  | bla  | A100        | bla
| 2  | bla  | A100.01     |
| 3  | bla  | A112        |
| 4  | bla  | A112.02
```

How do I do a select like this

```
SELECT projectcode
  , sum(debit) as debit
  , sum(credit) as credit
  , sum(budget) as budget
FROM table1
GROUP BY -insert-answer-here-
```

I want the output to `group by` A100 and A100.01 and A100.x together as well as A112 + A112.x

How do I do this?

**I have no control over the structure of the table.**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
GROUP BY LEFT(projectcode ,CHARINDEX('.',projectcode  + '.')-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this would work:

```
SELECT Substring(projectcode, 1, 4) as Project
  , sum(debit) as debit
  , sum(credit) as credit
  , sum(budget) as budget
FROM table1
GROUP BY Substring(projectcode, 1, 4)
```

Comment: You can't use an output value to group by, you have to specify the expression in both places.

Answer (score 1):

If the project code always follows the same pattern (cnnn / cnnn.nn) you can just get the first four characters:

```
group by substring(projectcode, 1, 4)
```

Comment: the length of the prefix (`A100` etc) differs.

Comment: @Johan: Ok, then you need to use `charindex` to locate the period in the string, as Martin showed.