# Using GROUP BY with dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an invoice date column in my table which contains data as below

```
20150131
20150231
20160128
20161231
```

I want to group the data based on the year of the transaction... i.e 2015 or 2016. My column type is `nvarchar`.

Can someone please help. I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do \`group by\` partial match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977506/how-do-i-do-group-by-partial-match)

Comment: Or if they're actually datetimes: [How to Group by Year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964094/how-to-group-by-year)

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: Can you show the result you need?

Comment: I think you want to filter your data not group it when you said 2015 or 2016, if yes; for 2015 use `WHERE date BETWEEN 20150000 AND 20160000` ;).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the column is integer, since integer division in SQL Server truncates the result, all you need to do is dividing out the lower four digits:

```
SELECT
    datefield/10000 AS Year
,   SUM(...) AS ...
FROM MyTable
WHERE ...
GROUP BY datefield/10000
```

If your column is a char or varchar, use `LEFT(datefield,4)` instead.

**Note:** I assume that you do not own the table, so switching to a more appropriate type (i.e. `date`) is not an option. Otherwise, I would strongly advise a switch, because `date` is smaller, and it also gives you access to date-specific functionality, such as extracting the day, the month, and the year.

Comment: That's assuming the data type is integer... if it's char then it should be using `LEFT(datefield, 4)` instead.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I am nearly certain that it's integer, because I've seen other people doing it for convenience instead of using `date`. It is hard to imagine why one would pick a string representation for a date, though, because it's larger and slower.

Comment: I tend to agree with your assumption, however I've seen my share of coding horrors. I've learned not to assume the obvious in these matters. So when in doubt, I usually ask or show both possibilities.

Comment: @Newbie So it *is* a string then. That's probably the worst of choice of the three possibilities. If you can convert your table to use `date` instead, I strongly advise you to do so. Add a `date` column, run an update to transfer the content from strings to date, then drop the string column.

Answer (score 1):

If your dates are valid, then simply you can use this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY YEAR(CAST(myDate AS DATETIME))
```

But if your dates are not valid(as is now, because February has 28 days), you can try this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY SUBSTRING(myDate,1,4)
```

Or

```
SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY Left(myDate,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use datepart function;

```
select DATEPART(year,CONVERT(date,col,105)),COUNT(*) from table_1
group by DATEPART(year,CONVERT(date,col,105))
```